# Are there onLoad/onError events triggered when embeding flash object in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm embeding flash player in HTML by inlining such HTML:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0"
width="470" height="320">
<param name="movie" value="http://myserver.com/app.swf"></param>
<param name="FlashVars" value="src=http://myserver.com/mymovie.flv"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://myserver.com/strobe/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    allowscriptaccess="always" width="470" height="320"
    FlashVars="src=http://myserver.com/mymovie.flv">
</embed>
</object>
```

I would like to receive callback onLoad or onError informing if the SWF application was properly downloaded and initialized. Is is possible? Does flash plugin expose such events for javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you embed the SWF with [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api), it's `embedSWF()` method has an optional callback parameter that you can use to know if embedding has completed successfully or failed.

Here is the method signature:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrlStr, replaceElemIdStr, widthStr, heightStr, swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, flashvarsObj, parObj, attObj, callbackFn)
```

I've never seen any other way to get this information, but then again I always use SWFObject :)

Comment: It seems to be the only way, although I can't produce conditions under which the callback function would return success=false. Even if the swfUrl is broken the callback is called with success=true.

Comment: I think SWFObject is probably just reporting that it successfully added the Flash object to the DOM, not necessarily  that it's loaded a valid SWF :(   If you must validate that your SWF is actually loaded and running you may want to use ExternalInterface to communicate w/the SWF after it's loaded.